# C# Windows Media Player video playing behind form

Tags: c#, video-player

I am trying to play a video after a certain event is triggered.
Currently the video starts playing but it stays behind the form (You can see it playing in the opacity of the toolbar). I have tried to bring it to the front, refresh it, select it, update it but none of it seems to work. Also, if I manually open the windows media player program and close it the video "jumps" to the front of the screen.

This is the code used to start playing the video

```
wmp.settings.autoStart = true;
wmp.uiMode = "none";
wmp.Visible = true;
wmp.URL = @"C:\folder\video.mp4";
wmp.Update();
```

I also check if the video is still playing using the Status_Change event to set it to full screen and try to bring it to front

```
private void wmp_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (wmp.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        wmp.fullScreen = true;
        wmp.BringToFront();
        wmp.Update();
    }
}
```

Despite these efforts the video still plays behind the form. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to embed WMP as a child control.  That starts by right-clicking the toolbox > Choose Items > COM Components tab > tick "Windows Media Player".  Drag the added control from the toolbox onto a form.